# Cannot use int on fractions. Workaround? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am loading in random lines from a CSV into a class. I need the system to see one of those values as a number and not a string to use for calculations. This works fine for whole numbers.

```
class Weapon:
    def __init__ (self, name, value, damage, weight, properties, catagory, description):
        self.name = name
        self.value = int(value)
        self.damage = damage
        self.weight = weight
        self.properties = properties
        self.catagory = catagory
        self.description = description
```

I have a problem where if I try to use int on a fraction (for example 0.05) I get the following error:

```
    self.value = int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.05'
```

What can I use instead of Int, or as well as int, to get it working?

Comment: If `value` needs to be an integer, it might be worth considering how a floating point value is being passed to `Weapon.__init__` in the first place.

Comment: Keep in mind the issue is that `'0.05'` is not a fraction. It's a string. What you're doing is the same as doing `int('Hello, World!')`.

Comment: Rather I would say that the problem here is that a fraction is not an int. Expecting `int('0.05')` to work is perhaps not reasonable in any case. :-)

Comment: True, I had misunderstood what int did. The PDF I was working from where I learnt about int told me if I wanted the system to treat numeric figures as a number instead of a string, I would have to use int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `int(float(value))` to first parse the string into a `float`, then convert to an `int`.

But of course, then `0.05` will be reduced to `0`. If that's not OK with you, just use `float(value)`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! Btw I will accept when the system allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
from decimal import Decimal
int(Decimal(value))
```

Don't use floats, floats are ugly.

Comment: floats are typically fine ... but you are right decimal's have precision goin for them

Comment: Why use Decimal if you're going to round off anyway?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: well, they could give different results if the number's too large to fit in a float.  ("Large" is probably the wrong word here: I mean "too many significant digits to the left of the decimal point".)

Comment: @TimPietzcker  in this specific case it may not matter (depending on what values are coming in).  But if you have a fixed precision value like would come in from a file, a Decimal is a better fit.